# How to solve the limit:$ \lim_{x \to 0,y \to 0} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I confronted a problem, that is

$$
\lim_{x \to 0,y \to 0} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}
$$

I tried to use $x=r\cos(\theta) , y=r\sin(\theta)$ to solve the problem, and I got 
$$\lim_{r \to 0}r(\frac{\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^3(\theta)+\sin^3(\theta)})$$
And no matter what value $\theta$ takes, we all have the limit is zero.

My question is:
(1) Am I right? Or
(2) If we can change the limit into such "$rf(\theta)$" form, when r goes to zero, will the limit go to zero?

Comment: You have $x,y \to \infty$ but you take $r \to 0$...?

Comment: I am sorry... Now the question is right

Comment: If $f$ is bounded when $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, the limit will go to 0.

Comment: @LittleCuteKemono Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=0$, then the limit is $0$. However$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^2\left(-\frac1n\right)^2}{\left(\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^3+\left(-\frac1n\right)^3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{3n^2+3n+1}=\frac13.$$

Comment: So that means this limit does not exist? Since if we let x = y then the limit is 0.

Comment: Right, the limit does not exist. Why do you care about what happens when $x=y$. Yes, then the limit is $0$, but you already know that the limit is $0$ along the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thank you, and I have a question again: how to prove or disprove the limit, your solution is really amazing but I think it's a bit hard  to construct , so could you tell me what do you think when you see such question?

Comment: Sure. I thought that the function is undefined when $x=-y$. So, I saw what happens at points $(x,y)$ with $x\neq-y$ but such that they approach quickly points of the type $(x,-x)$. That's why I took$$\left(\frac1n,-\frac1n\right)+\left(\frac1{n^2},0\right).$$

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative note that

- $x=0 \,,y\to 0\implies \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}=0$
- $x=t \,, y=t^2-t\,,t\to 0 \implies \frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}=\frac{t^2(t^2-t)^2}{t^3+(t^2-t)^3}=\frac{t^6-2t^5+t^4}{t^3+t^6-3t^5+3t^4-t^3}=\frac{t^2-2t+1}{t^2-3t+3}\to \frac13$